# Django form shows as unbound even if instantiated with model instance

Tags: django, django-forms

I am having difficulties with using the admittedly pretty snazzy properties of the Django form and ModelForm classes.  In particular I am having trouble determining if a form instance has data associated when it is instantiated with a model instance.

First here's a look at a pretty simple set of forms in `forms.py`

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import ItemCoeff, MonthCoeff

class MonthForm(ModelForm):
"""A class that defines an HTML form that will be constructed for interfacing with the Monthly Coefficients"""

title='Set Month Coefficient'
class Meta:
    model=MonthCoeff

    fields = ['first_of_month', 'product_category', 'month_coeff', 'notes']

class ItemForm(ModelForm):
"""
A class that defines a Django HTML form to be constructed for interfacing with the ItemCoeff model.
"""
title='Set Item Coefficient'

class Meta:
    model=ItemCoeff
    fields = ['item_num','item_name','item_coeff','notes']
```

Next we get to the part of `views.py` where I use the form

```
def set_month_form(request, myid=False):
if myid:
    mcoeff=MonthCoeff.objects.get(id=myid)
    form=MonthForm(instance = mcoeff)
    categories = False
else:
    form=MonthForm()
    categories=list(MonthCoeff.objects.values('product_category').distinct())
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
return render(request,'coeffs/forms/django_form.html',{'form':form, 'user': request.user})
```

And when I am rendering the form in my template I am trying to use the is_bound property to set the caption of my submit button, like so:

```
{% if form.is_bound %}
        <button type="submit" name="button">Update</button>
{% else %}
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="button">Add</button>
{% endif %}
```

This approach however, always yields the `else` condition.  As I'm sure you noticed, I set a pdb trace in my `view.py` code and when I examine the form object just prior to rendering the `form.is_bound` returns `False`. This happens even when `form['first_of_month']` returns the value associated with the MonthCoeff instance that was used to create the form.

Does anyone have any insights into why the is_bound property is not responding as I have been lead to expect from the otherwise wonderful [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-bound-unbound)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But you haven't bound it to data. You've supplied an instance parameter, but that's not the same thing at all; that just associates the form with a model instance that supplies initial values and something to update on save. Bound vs unbound is determined by whether you pass any data, usually from the POST.

If you want to change the button depending on whether there's an instance, then just do that:

```
{% if form.instance %}
        <button type="submit" name="button">Update</button>
{% else %}
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="button">Add</button>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm.  I was having trouble separating out "bound" vs. "instance".  I forgot you can evaluate properties such as instance as booleans in Python.  Too much time working in crappier languages.